# Annotate QuerySet by the complements of the related objects set in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

What would be a good way to annotate each object in a queryset by another queryset in Django? I'd like to annotate each object in a queryset by a queryset of related model objects, which don't have active relation to the object. That is, annotate a queryset by the *complements* of the related objects set.

Perhaps it's easier to consider the following simple stripped down models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    pass

class Voting(models.Model):
     votes = models.ManyToManyField(Member)
```

And now, consider a simple queryset:

```
votings = Voting.objects.all()
```

All these Voting objects have `votes` field which contains a set of Member objects that have voted. Is it possible to annotate each Voting object with a set of Member objects that have not voted yet in that voting? Motivation: I'd like to list all (or some filtered set of) Votings and show the votes of each member and also show the members that haven't yet voted.

One possible solution:

```
votings = list(votings)
for voting in votings:
    voting.not_voted_members = Member.objects.exclude(voting=voting)
```

But this requires a database query for each voting, which doesn't sound good. Perhaps it's better to do the annotation in Python:

```
members = Member.objects.all()
for voting in votings:
    voting.not_voted_members = [member for member in members
                                if member not in voting.votes.all()]
```

But is there a better way? In particular, I'm wondering if I can do this kind of annotation by using, for instance, the annotate method on the Voting queryset, or something similar?

Comment: Your second method also has multiple database queries. In short: you just want to know who has not voted. Is that right?

Comment: Ah, true, `voting.votes.all()` hits the database. Yes, for each voting, I want to know who have not yet voted.

Comment: But if I'm now understanding correctly, even getting the members that have voted already via `voting.votes.all()` hits the database for each voting. So getting the voted members for each voting isn't basically any more efficient. Is it possible to annotate those sets to the voting objects by using one (or only a few) database queries?